# mysql2 gem build error when installing redmine

Tags: debian, raspbian, gem

when i tried installing redmine with `bundle install --without development test`
I received this build error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...................................
Installing rake 10.3.2
...(and so on)

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/pi/.rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

...

Gem files will remain installed in /home/pi/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/mysql2-0.3.17 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/pi/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/extensions/armv6l-linux/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.17/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.17), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried reading `.gem/ruby/2.1.5/extensions/armv6l-linux/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.17/mkmf.log` which is full of gcc code checking output with error messages similar in those present in basic output which I've posted abowe.

I've also tried executing command from error message (`gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'`) but of course this also failed with same result. What can be the source of those errors? I am rather new to linux environment so I let automats do everything for me and I'm following guides ([this one in this case](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Step-4-Dependencies-installation))

Can there be a problem with mysql that is already installed by apt-get along with apache?

P.S.
It is raspbian/debian distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a solution

what solved my problem is one (or both) of those two installations:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

probably the later one

i have installed both before checking, so i can't be sure